# ANTLR mixing INT with FLOAT

Tags: floating-point, int, antlr

I have a simple antlr rule to catch a phrase like "running.exception=2.j=15" and I want to identify the value is initialized to which is 2 in this case.

However, ANTLR is looking at 2. as a float. Is there anyway to make it identify it as an int?

My rule:

```
exception
    :
    (
    ID*
    '.exception='
    INT
    '.'
    ID*
    );
```

Comment: tried to add (('0'..'9') '.' CHAR) {$type=INT;} to float but it considered 2.j to be INT!

Comment: but sometimes 2.5 is a float but 2.j is 2 as INT and j as ID. The previous rule I added to FLOAT and it caught 2.j as INT. ANY suggestions?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. See if my answer solves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : (t=. {System.out.printf("\%-10s '\%s'\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text);})* EOF
 ;

FLOAT
 : DIGIT+ ( ('.' DIGIT)=> '.' DIGIT+
          | {$type=INT;}
          )
 | '.' DIGIT+
 ;

DOT
 : '.'
 ;

SPACE
 : ' ' {skip();}
 ;

fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
fragment INT : ;
```

which would parse the input `"0.12 .34 56. 78"` like this:

```
FLOAT      '0.12'
FLOAT      '.34'
INT        '56'
DOT        '.'
INT        '78'
```